# Is there a proof that a sum of torques equals a net torque?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, torque

I apologize for asking a question similar to this before, where in particular I asked for a derivation of Fr = Iα from the presuppositions of F = MA and the conservation of angular momentum. However, all the derivations just presupposed that a sum of mini-torques equals the actual torque, the actual torque being the “real“ force applied a certain distance away from the axis of rotation. I grant that a sum of multiple forces equals a net force, but that doesn’t imply in itself that a sum of multiple torques equals a net torque.

I’ll give an example. Consider 2 particles, A and B, of the same mass which have a massless rod piercing through them keeping them aligned to each other. Particle A is 2 meters away from the axis of rotation, B 1 meter. Why is it so that when I apply a force of 2.5 Newtons on A, almost in an instant B has 1 Newton of force applied onto it, and A only 2 Newtons? According to Fr = Iα, applying 2.5 Newtons onto A produces the same effect as originally applying 2 Newtons to A and 1 Newton to B.(Only taking into account the force perpendicular to rotation. Obviously 2.5 does not equal 1+2, so centripetal acceleration is accounting for some of the perceived “extra” force).

I do not want a proof in terms of energy. Energy is after all derived from the force and kinematics equations, so if you could prove this problem in terms of energy, you should be able to prove it in terms of force and kinematics.

I’m guessing the proof would require to not only take into account the torque, but also a centripetal force.

Comment: "Why is it so that when I apply a force of 2.5 Newtons on A, almost in an instant B has 1 Newton of force applied onto it, and A only 2 Newtons?" Can you explain what you mean by this?  I think you have a physical situation in mind involving some deformable bodies.  Understanding the nature of this would help greatly in helping you find out why the physics works.

Comment: @CortAmmon let’s say I were to push a block. I only apply a force at one particular point on a block consisting of many points. In my mind, that force gets distributed to each particle in the block due to the forces between each particle. So instead of only one particle being pushed with the entire brunt of the force, the force gets “distributed” to all the other particles that compose the block, due to intermolecular forces. I’m thinking it’s the same with torque

Comment: In that situation, the one particle actually *does* get pushed with the entire brunt of the force the entire time.  However, due to those intermolecular forces, there will be reactionary forces between that one particle and its neighbors which oppose that force.  This is an important detail because we can see that the intermolecular forces and their reactionary counterparts sum to 0 torque and we can ignore them for analyzing the torques on the whole body (until we actually consider deformation).

Comment: Indeed, one of the most powerful aspects of analyzing an object as a rigid body is that any internal forces or torques always have an equal and opposite force/torque reaction from another particle in the object.  These sum to 0, and this lets us analyze these rigid bodies without having to pay attention to the details of their internal structure.

Comment: @CortAmmon Now I understand that a particle does receive the “full brunt,” but just has less acceleration because of reactionary forces. But I don’t see how we can derive torque solely from force

Comment: @CortAmmon if for example, I were to live in a world where things always collided with each other so that their center of mass were perfectly aligned, would I be able to discover torque?(assuming that torque could be produced in that world, but by some miracle all collisions were perfectly aligned)

Comment: Ahh, that last question helps.  Let me see if I can put something together as an answer.  The basic gist is that forces and torques are one and the same, but one is easier to use when things can move linearly, and one is easier to use when things can rotate.  It may take me a bit to write the answer, but the basic answer is that if you write the summations over all particles, you can derive torque from force, and vice versa.

Comment: The torque is shown to be a pseudovector, and as such they can be added into a summed torque

Comment: @Wolphramjonny yes I understand that vectors can be added together. But what’s true in mathematics is not always true for the observed world. I can say that my height is the combined height of every person in my family, and hence I’d be 18 feet tall. Mathematically, I am correct, if each family member is 6 feet tall, and there’s 3 members of my family. But the presupposition that my height is a sum of the heights of my family members, is wrong. Likewise, the presupposition that torque is a vector with certain properties is in question here, and not whether vectors can be added together.

Comment: It is not difficult to show it is a vector, just use the definition, make a transformation of coordinates and see if the torque transforms as a vector

Comment: @Wolphramjonny if we start off from a definition of torque, then we’d not be proving torque exists from Newton’s second law or the conservation of angular momentum, but rather assuming torque exists empirically. Imagine a world where all objects collide so that their center of masses were aligned together. In this world, to discover torque we can’t rely on a definition of torque, because we’ve never seen torque. 

I want someone to derive torque from the principles of F=MA and intermolecular forces that keep a body rigid.

Comment: But torque is just s definition, $rxF$ so you can easily show it behaves like a pseudovertor, or vector for all practical purposes. That is all you need, right?

Comment: @Wolphramjonny  I’m just wondering if we can derive torque theoretically. If we cannot derive torque from a summation of forces, then that would mean that our world is defined by two principles: torque and force, which just sounds  unnatural. If torque can be derived from a summation of forces, then we can explain our entire world in terms of forces. Certainly, it would be impractical to take into account all forces acting on a body when dealing with rotation, but I just want to know definitively that our world is made of forces. Nothing wrong with that, right?

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean by deriving torque theoretically, it is a definition: rxF, and that's it.

Comment: @Wolphramjonny sure, torque is a definition. Just like the the definition of the orbit of planets is “elliptical.” But that the orbits of our planets are elliptical can be proved using force and kinematics. Torque likewise, or at least I suppose, can be too.

If our world was just kinematics and forces, we could describe torque in terms of kinematics and forces, and that’s what I want. 

If for example, we can take into account all the forces on each particle of a rotating system, and find that each particle accelerates according to Fr=Iα, I’d be satisfied.

Comment: it is not defined to be elliptical, it is deducted to be that way after applying newton's laws

Comment: @Wolphramjonny you seemed to have missed my point. I meant that you can call torque a definition, but that doesn’t mean torque can’t be derived from other principles. Torque, centripetal acceleration, the conservation of momentum or angular momentum all have definitions, but they can all be derived from force and kinematics formulas.

Comment: It is a useful definition that is it. And you can show it is a vector, etc, I dont really understand what your point is.